# How is cross-validation used for logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, stepwise-regression

I have a fundamental question about cross-validation in logistic regression. I would really appreciate some help since something is still unclear to me. My situation is the following: I split my data set into training, validation and test set. When using for example rpart for classification trees on a training set, it automatically splits it into k-folds (basically creating a validation set) and suggests an optimal complexity parameter. I can then run the suggested tree on my test set. However, if I run a logistic regression. Let's say I run a stepwise regression model (although I know stepwise regression model have to be used with caution). How can I use cross-validation to improve my model? Since, by using different folds, I will get models with different numbers of features. How can I choose one to eventually run it on my test set? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @ user777 Thank you for the reply. My problem is that I need to compare classification trees to logistic regression. Although a lot of people recommended alternative approaches. What I don't really get is how I can use cross-validation in a logistic regression framework. Is it then just to randomise the split of training and testing set?

Comment: The idea is that no matter what model output you get, you apply that model to the holdout data. So in the stepwise context, it doesn't matter if there are different models (different feature sets) between folds. Apply the model, and measure your chosen performance metric.